# How is matrix B built?

Tags: linear-algebra

I am trying to understand section 3.1 of [this paper](http://www.cipa.dcu.ie/papers/ivc_2005_jm.pdf), where it says:

> Assuming an imperfect $F$ matrix, the solution for $H′$ can be robustly found in a least squares sense from equation (4) by the SVD of $Bp = 0$, where $p = \begin{bmatrix}h′_{21} & h′_{22} & h′_{23} & h′_{31} & h′_{32} & h′_{33} & \alpha\end{bmatrix}^{T}$

Equation (4) is:

$\begin{bmatrix}
(h_{21} h'_{31} - h_{31} h'_{21}) & h'_{31} & -h′_{21} \\
(h_{21} h'_{32} - h_{31} h'_{22}) & h'_{32} & -h′_{22} \\
(h_{21} h'_{33} - h_{31} h'_{23}) & h'_{33} & -h′_{23} \\
\end{bmatrix} = \alpha
\begin{bmatrix}
f_{11} & f_{12} & f_{13} \\
f_{21} & f_{22} & f_{23} \\
f_{31} & f_{32} & f_{33} \\
\end{bmatrix}$

I calculated equation 4 correctly from the previous results, but I cannot understand **how $B$ is constructed**, giving there is no other reference to it in the paper and $p$ is a column 7-vector. In theory $B$ should be a 7xn matrix for the equation to be valid, but here I have only 3x3 matrices?

Comment: Please comment on why the question is not valid, if you have to downvote.

Comment: Fixed link to the paper.

Comment: Thank you very responsible to downvote and not comment.

Comment: $$
\mathbf{H'}^\top \bar{\mathbf{F}} \mathbf{H}  = 
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0\\
h'_{21} & h'_{22} & h'_{23}\\
h'_{31} & h'_{32} & h'_{33}\\
\end{pmatrix}^\top
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & -1\\
0 & 1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0\\
h_{21} & 1 & 0\\
h_{31} & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix} = 
\begin{pmatrix}
h_{21}h'_{31} -h_{31}h'_{21}& h'_{31} & -h'_{21}\\
h_{21}h'_{32} -h_{31}h'_{22}& h'_{32} & -h'_{22}\\
h_{21}h'_{33} -h_{31}h'_{23}& h'_{33} & -h'_{23}\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Comment: @uranix thanks, but that is what I already figured out. The question is about the next step.

Comment: Treat that equality as 9 separate linear equations in $h', \alpha$

Comment: @uranix you mean like: $h_{21} h′_{31} − h_{31} h′_{21} = \alpha f_{11}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The matrix equality $$\begin{bmatrix}
(h_{21} h'_{31} - h_{31} h'_{21}) & h'_{31} & -h′_{21} \\
(h_{21} h'_{32} - h_{31} h'_{22}) & h'_{32} & -h′_{22} \\
(h_{21} h'_{33} - h_{31} h'_{23}) & h'_{33} & -h′_{23} \\
\end{bmatrix} = \alpha
\begin{bmatrix}
f_{11} & f_{12} & f_{13} \\
f_{21} & f_{22} & f_{23} \\
f_{31} & f_{32} & f_{33} \\
\end{bmatrix}$$
can be viewed as 9 equations
$$
h_{21} h'_{31} - h_{31} h'_{21} - f_{11} \alpha = 0\\
h_{21} h'_{32} - h_{31} h'_{22} - f_{21} \alpha = 0\\
h_{21} h'_{33} - h_{31} h'_{23} - f_{31} \alpha = 0\\
h_{31}' - f_{12} \alpha = 0\\
h_{32}' - f_{22} \alpha = 0\\
h_{33}' - f_{32} \alpha = 0\\
-h_{21}' - f_{13} \alpha = 0\\
-h_{22}' - f_{23} \alpha = 0\\
-h_{23}' - f_{33} \alpha = 0
$$
The corresponding matrix $B$ is
$$
B = 
\begin{pmatrix}
-h_{31} & 0 & 0 & h_{21} & 0 & 0 & -f_{11}\\
0 & -h_{31} & 0 & 0 & h_{21} & 0 & -f_{21}\\
0 & 0 & -h_{31} & 0 & 0 & h_{21} & -f_{31}\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & -f_{12}\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & -f_{22}\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & -f_{32}\\
-1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -f_{13}\\
0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -f_{23}\\
0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -f_{33}
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Comment: Great. I hypothesized you could do an element-to-element equation, and then build the system with the coefficients, but I had absolutely no idea if it made mathematical sense. Thanks a bunch!